# Custom redirect path if Registration fails on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I want to change the redirect path when the `Registration` fails in `Laravel 5.3` right it redirects to the previous page but I want to change it and I can't find out where.

## Here is the RegisterController

```
<?php
use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}


protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
?>
```

## And here is the RegistersUsers trait

```
<?php
use RedirectsUsers;


public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}

protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{

}
?>
```

Is there any ideas on how to achieve that, because I want to make a register `Modal` on the home page, and since it's a modal the user can't see the errors until he opens the registration `Modal` again, I want to make the **Failed Registration attempts ** always redirects to /register.

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `RedirectsUsers` `register` function in `RegisterController` as following.

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    if(empty($user)) { // Failed to register user
        redirect('/register'); // Wherever you want to redirect
    }

    event(new Registered($user));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    // Success redirection - which will be attribute `$redirectTo`
    redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: this does not work